# Typescript : question mark on array

Tags: typescript

This is the skeleton of my code :

```
var myArray: (Array<any> | null);
if (cnd) {
  myArray = [];
  myArray?.push(elt); // Question 1
  myArray[0].key = value; //Question 2
} else {
  myArray = null;
}
```

Question 1 : Why `?` is needed ? myArray has been assigned to an empty array.

Question 2 : What is the syntax to avoid error : Object is possibly null.

Thanks for answer.

Comment: Re: question 1, testing in the TS playground, I *don't* need the conditional operator: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?code/G4QwTgBAxgdgJhAvBAsiALgCwHRhPAewFsAKASggD4IAGbAVgG4AoUSAUwBt0kIBmFmwihOAV3a8mzVuAhEAngEEweeQC4IJZaoA8+edQA+EGKM6cyLAJYAzTbDgUA3swhylKkPN4BtALosbgraXtgADqIAzpgkXOiWEAD0iRAAiuKR6FYEMBAAjK7uIfI+NH7YANbs3sgi4oxJiensmdm5AEzMAL4QXJESLkEeqrym5ixdQA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For question 1, you can refer to this [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining)

For question 2, just perform a check against `null` like this before accessing your object

```
if (obj !== null) {
    obj.doSomeThing();
}
```

or just simply like the following if your object can be `null` or `undefined`. `null` and `undefined` are what are called falsy value, so when they are used in a boolean context, they are automatically coerced to `false`

```
if (obj) {
    obj.doSomeThing();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is that humans are still smarter than typecheckers. I know that's not satisfying, but it's true. The typechecker typically uses just conditional statements to determine whether something can be null. But this code example feels a little contrived. I would probably restructure the code like this:

```js
var myArray: (Array<any> | null);
if (cnd) {
  elt.key = value;
  myArray = [elt];
} else {
  myArray = null;
}
```

This removes those two oddities.

Comment: I like you remark " humans are still smarter than typecheckers"

Comment: I am sorry. I accept the other answer because of my full code but I am sure your answer will help me in the future. Pity, that is not possible to accept 2 answers.